# Generate JQM Popup Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to display a JQM PopUp based on the contents of my variable.

I have a variable that contains this.

`924-1922, 928-3074, 928-8363`

Then I perform `.split` so I can get the three phone numbers.

`secNumber = res.rows.item(i).secondary_num.split(", ");`

So my variable `secNumber` now has an array of three numbers: `924-1922,928-3074,928-8363`

Now here is my code for displaying it (I am using for loop for this since there are many entries with phone numbers):

```
html += '<a href="#" class="category-btn" title="All" rel="external" >'+ res.rows.item(i).name  +' <br> <span style="font-size: 15px;color: #778084;" onclick="window.open(\'tel:02'+telnum+'\', \'_system\');"> Tel. No.:  ' + res.rows.item(i).tel_num + ' </span> <br> <span style="font-size: 15px;color: #778084;" onclick="window.open(\'tel:02'+secNumber+'\', \'_system\');"> ' + secondary  +' </span> </a>';
```

The `onclick` on my last `<span>` is working. However, it only puts the first number on the phone's dialer. What I want to achieve on my `onclick` is, after show a popup onclick using this code from JQM website

```
<a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="gear" data-theme="e">Actions...</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="d">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;" data-theme="d">
        <li data-role="divider" data-theme="e">Choose an action</li>
        <li><a href="#">View details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Disable</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click on my `<span>` the contents of the listview of the popup will be the contents of my array `secNumber`, then on the `onclick` of each element in the listview, I will call window.open to access the phone's dialer.

**EDIT** 
This is my code.

```
article.emergency = function() {


var secNumber;
var telnum;

var html = '';
appDB.transaction(function(tx) {
     tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM emergency", [], function(tx, res) {
          if (res.rows.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

                   function openPopup(index) {
                      //reset its content
                      $('#popupMenu').find('ul').html('<li data-role="divider" data-theme="e">Choose an action</li>');

                      //loop on secondary_num items
                      $.each(res.rows.item(index).secondary_num.split(", "), function(k, v) {
                         $('#popupMenu').find('ul').append('<li><a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'tel:02' + v + '\', \'_system\');">' + v + '</a></li>');
                      });

                      //refresh listView
                      $('#popupMenu').find('ul').listview("refresh");
                      //open popup
                      $('#popupMenu').popup("open", {"transition":"slideup"});
                }


                   var secondary = (res.rows.item(i).secondary_num != 'null') ?  'Secondary Number: ' + res.rows.item(i).secondary_num : '';
                   secNumber = res.rows.item(i).secondary_num.split(", ");
                   console.log(secNumber);
                   /*secondary = secondary.replace(/-/g,"");
                   console.log("Secondary number string : "+secondary);*/
                   console.log(res.rows.item(i).tel_num);
                   telnum = res.rows.item(i).tel_num.split(" to");
                   console.log(telnum);
                   html += '<a href="#" class="category-btn" title="All" rel="external" >'+ res.rows.item(i).name  +' <br> <span style="font-size: 15px;color: #778084;" onclick="window.open(\'tel:02'+telnum+'\', \'_system\');"> Tel. No.:  ' + res.rows.item(i).tel_num + ' </span> <br> <span style="font-size: 15px;color: #778084;" onclick="window.open(\'tel:02'+secNumber+'\', \'_system\');"> ' + secondary  +' </span> </a>';
                   //html += '<a href="#" class="category-btn" title="All" rel="external" >'+ res.rows.item(i).name  +' <br> <span style="font-size: 15px;color: #778084;" onclick="window.open(\'tel:02'+telnum+'\', \'_system\');"> Tel. No.:  ' + res.rows.item(i).tel_num + ' </span> <br> <span style="font-size: 15px;color: #778084;" onclick="window.open(\'tel:02'+secNumber+'\', \'_system\');"> ' + secondary  +' </span> </a>';
              }

               $('.list-display').html(html); 
          }
     });

}, article.onErr, article.onSuccess);
}
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: can setup a fiddle to clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi sir @Omar I am finding a a hard time to display it in fiddle. Can I talk to you in a more detailed way rather than fiddle? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you can update your question with any extra helpful detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your `item` array has multiple elements and you want to use a unique `popup` container you'll have to generate dynamically its content (refreshing the listView widget).

Your secondary span should look similar to

```
<span onclick="window.openPopup(' + index + ');"> ' + secondary  +' </span>
```

and your openPopup function

```
function openPopup(index) {
    //reset its content
    $('#popupMenu').find('ul').html('<li data-role="divider" data-theme="e">Choose an action</li>');

    //loop on secondary_num items
    var secNumber = item[index].secondary_num.split(", ");
    for (var i = 0; i < secNumber.length; i++) {
        $('#popupMenu').find('ul').append('<li><a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'tel:02' + secNumber[i] + '\', \'_system\');">' + secNumber[i] + '</a></li>');
    }

    //refresh listView
    $('#popupMenu').find('ul').listview("refresh");
    //open popup
    $('#popupMenu').popup("open", {"transition":"slideup"});
}
```

Here you can fine a **working example** with a simplified structure: http://jsfiddle.net/phtzwxb6/5/

Update fixing your code with a possible solution:

```
// declared outside
function openPopup(index) {
    //reset its content
    $('#popupMenu').find('ul').html('<li data-role="divider" data-theme="e">Choose an action</li>');

    //loop on secondary_num items
    var secNumber = item[index].secondary_num.split(", ");
    for (var i = 0; i < secNumber.length; i++) {
        $('#popupMenu').find('ul').append('<li><a href="#" onclick="window.open(\'tel:02' + secNumber[i] + '\', \'_system\');">' + secNumber[i] + '</a></li>');
    }

    //refresh listView
    $('#popupMenu').find('ul').listview("refresh");
    //open popup
    $('#popupMenu').popup("open", {"transition":"slideup"});
}

//your enclosure...

article.emergency = function() {
    var secNumber;
    var telnum;

    var html = '';
    appDB.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM emergency", [], function(tx, res) {
                    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {

                            var secondary = (res.rows.item(i).secondary_num != 'null') ?  'Secondary Number: ' + res.rows.item(i).secondary_num : '';
                            secNumber = res.rows.item(i).secondary_num.split(", ");

                            telnum = res.rows.item(i).tel_num.split(" to");
                            html += '<a href="#" class="category-btn" title="All" rel="external" >'+ res.rows.item(i).name  +' <br> <span style="font-size: 15px;color: #778084;" onclick="window.open(\'tel:02'+telnum+'\', \'_system\');"> Tel. No.:  ' + res.rows.item(i).tel_num + ' </span> <br> <span style="font-size: 15px;color: #778084;" onclick="window.openPopup(' + i + ');"> ' + secondary  +' </span> </a>';

                        }

                        $('.list-display').html(html); 
                    }
            });

    }, article.onErr, article.onSuccess);
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, I am new to `.each`. Is this doable in a for loop?

Comment: Hi @Andrea Tondo, I have updated my code. Can I do your code in a for loop?

Comment: @MiguelRivera, I've updated the above code and the jsfiddle example replacing $.each with a for loop.
Based on the code you provided, you should also pull openPopup function out of appDB.transaction, and replace window.open with window.openPopup function call in html var.

Comment: @MiguelRivera I've updated the answer with a possible solution using the code you provided.